# WinForm ListView Layout Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

`enter code here`I'm having an issue with setting the layout for my ListView. I must be missing something simple.

All I want is a list that has one item per row and instead its making the list run from left to right.

[image]

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Items = new List<Item>();
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Path", listView1.Width, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}

public void Blah(){
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Item item in Items)
    {
       string s = String.Format("{1}", item.Type, item.Path);
       ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
       lvi.Text = s;
       listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Found it..

add `listView1.View = View.Details;` to the constructor and magic happens.

I hope this saves someone some time.[image]